# Designing a generic yet flexible internal service response object

Tags: scala, traits

I want to create a custom response object that is both generic and flexible in nature.

I sort of modelled this based on amazon's response codes for their API.

An example usage would be something like:

```
val response: AddProductResponse = shoppingcartService.addProduct(product)
```

I was thinking of something like:

1. success/failure
2. error message collection
3. error code
4. custom payload which could be an Object, List, Map

The error codes should support pattern matching, which I believe I can use traits correct?

Looking for some help on how to design this using scala 'best practises'.

This is what I was thinking (pseudo code), but please provide your feedback based on whatever idea you have and not based on mine.

```
trait BaseResponse {
  def success: Boolean
  def errorCode: ErrorCode
  def errorMessages: List[String]
}

sealed abstract trait ErrorCode
case class OutOfStock() extends ErrorCode
case class ExceededMaxQuantity() extends ErrorCode

trait OutOfStock extends ErrorCode

case class AddProductResponse(products: Option[List[Product]]) extends BaseResponse
```

So the above AddProductResponse is generic in the sense that it will response with success/failure, and it returns an error code along with a list of error messages.
The specific part of it is that it returns a list of products if the response was a success (so I wrapped it in an Option).

I have never really design any sort of class/trait heirarchy before in scala so looking for all the feedback I can get.

Comment: Do you target your api to be scala only?

Comment: Yes, it is an 100% scala operation and this api is not a true api per say it is really just a set of "service" classes and it all lives in the same jvm.  But if it ever gets to a point where a particular service needs to be isolated I can refactor it easily to a true api call.